# Stuck on a loop C++

Tags: c++, for-loop, factorial

I'm trying to do a factorial 
a factorial takes in a number through user input then does this formula

```
input = 5;
5! = 5(4)(3)(2)(1)
```

the only thing is that  its saying can't use 'fac' as a function other than that the mathematics in it I think is right, yes.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int fac = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int cnt = 1;
    cout << "Input a number to get the Factorial: ";
    cin >> fac;

    for (fac; fac > 0; cnt ++)
    {
        sum = fac(fac - cnt)
    }

    cout << fac << "! : ";
}
```

Comment: `fac` is an `int`. The syntax `fac(fac - cnt)` makes no sense. You cannot call an `int`. It's like writing `5(5-1)`. What would it mean to call 5?

Comment: Also, `fac > 0` is an infinite loop (assuming `fac` starts out positive), because `fac` does not change inside the loop; you only change `sum` and `cnt`.

Comment: You have to `fac` that `cnt` really hard to make it work.

Answer (score 3):

In standard mathematics, adjacency means multiplication.  In most computer languages, it does not.

In C++, you must use the `*` operator to multiply two quantities:

```
    sum = fac * (fac - cnt)
```

However, you'll find that you have some other mathematical/logical bugs in your program too.  For example, you exit the loop when `fac > 0` is false, but you never modify `fac` in the loop.  So the loop will either execute zero times, or execute an infinite number of times.

Answer (score 3):

In C++ you cannot multiply by saying `4(2)` as we often do as shorthand in mathematics. You have to explicitly use `*`.

```
for( fac; fac > 0; cnt++ )
{
    sum = fac * (fac - cnt);
}
```

However this will not do what you want. Since you never modify `fac` this will loop forever. You want to multiply the current value by the running product.

```
int prod = 1;
for( i = fac; i > 0; --i ) // <-- notice the --i
    prod = prod * i;       // <-- equiv to prod *= i;
```

Now lets see what happens when we input `5`:

```
prod      i       new_prod
---------------------------
  1       5        1*5 = 5
  5       4        5*4 = 20
 20       3       20*3 = 60
 60       2       60*2 = 120
 120      1      120*1 = 120
 120
```

so the value of `prod` is the factorial. Just output it

```
 cout << fac << "! = " << prod << endl;
```

Comment: You can replace `i > 0` with `i > 1` and save one iteration ;)

Comment: so the input i was the equivalent to cnt? in the original code? not sure how i came into everything so kinda got confusing

Answer (score 0):

Apart from your other logic ,the error is arising due to fac(fac-cnt) . I think you are trying to multiply those variables . Try the following

`fac*(fac-cnt);`

Answer (score -1):

I find your question very unclear. Looks like you want a recursive method for calculating a! ...

Check out this

```
int fac(int n)
{
  return (n == 1 || n == 0) ? 1 : fac(n - 1) * n;
}
```

got it from here : [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/unices/33379/)

edit: gah! dont mind this answer, read to quickly